# How do i read scripts in h2 database

Tags: sql, spring, h2

This is the scripts for schema.SQL.  It shows error when it gets to the alter table section of the scripts:

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS billing_address;

    CREATE TABLE billing_address (
      id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      billingAddressCity varchar(255),
      billingAddressCountry varchar(255),
      billingAddressName varchar(255),
      billingAddressState varchar(255),
      billingAddressStreet1 varchar(255),
      billingAddressStreet2 varchar(255),
      billingAddressZipCode varchar(255),
      order_id bigint  (20),
      PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );



    alter table user_role drop constraint if exists FKa68196081fvovjhkek5m97n3y foreign key (role_id) references role (roleid);
    alter table user_role add constraint FKa68196081fvovjhkek5m97n3y foreign key (role_id) references role (roleid);


> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "ALTER TABLE BILLING_ADDRESS DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS FKN9O6NQ40AQJYEBAOFKOLMGV69 FOREIGN[*] KEY (ORDER_ID) REFERENCES USER_ID  "; SQL statement:
alter table billing_address drop constraint if exists FKn9o6nq40aqjyebaofkolmgv69 foreign key (order_id) references user_id  [42000-196]
```

Comment: There's a lot of code to scroll through before you get to the problem line. You should probably edit out the irrelevant parts of the script to make it a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I'm guessing that's why the question got downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The syntax for `drop constraint`](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#alter_table_drop_constraint.) doesn't expect the constraint definition, just the name. So try replacing

```
alter table billing_address drop constraint if exists FKn9o6nq40aqjyebaofkolmgv69
    foreign key (order_id) references user_id ;
```

with just

```
alter table billing_address drop constraint if exists FKn9o6nq40aqjyebaofkolmgv69 ;
```

And similarly for the rest of the following drop statements.